# Get Button.Content after Style was added in C# | Xaml

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

If I declare a Button's Content in my .xaml View like this:

```
<Button>
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hey" />
  </Grid>
</Button>
```

I can easily get it in my C# Code with Button.Content and cast it to a Grid.

But when I add a Style with ControlTemplate via Code and then want to get the content, it's always null...

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Style = App.Current.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;

Grid grid = btn.Content as Grid; //<-- Always null
```

My Style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Name="MyStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="Hey" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Button is correctly styled in the view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the text using following code:

```
        Grid g = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(btn, 0) as Grid;
        TextBlock t = g.Children[0] as TextBlock;
        string txt = t.Text;
```

Note you cannot use the code just after you created the button(I think the style had not been applied at that time). You can add another button, add the code in the click event.

Comment: Thanks mate! 
I'm wondering why this is the only opportunity...  

Button.ApplyTemplate helps me to get the UIElements in the next line :)